# Saber cuando el scroll llega al inicio o final del carousel con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código jquery:

```js
var fila = $('.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel');
var flechaIzquierda = $('#flecha-izquierda');
var flechaDerecha = $('#flecha-derecha');

$(flechaDerecha).on("click", function(){    
     var scrollDer = fila.scrollLeft() + fila.width();
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollDer);
     
});

$(flechaIzquierda).on("click", function(){     
     var scrollIzq = fila.scrollLeft() - fila.width(); 
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollIzq);
});
```

```css
    /* Carousel Productos y Categorias */
    
    .panel{
        width: 280px;
        height: 331px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .a-carrito{
        color: #FF0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 230px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .producto .panel-body{
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
    
    .panel img{
        display: block;
        width: 140px;
        height: 210px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .panel .p-precio{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #3FDE20;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    
    .panel .p-producto{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha{
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: #000;
        font-size: 40px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 40%;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 500;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .2s ease all;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda{
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha{
        right: 0;
    }
    
    /* ---- ----- ----- Carousel ----- ----- ----- */
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 33px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto{
        min-width: 280px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto.hover{
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transform-origin: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productos-recomendados">
      <h2 class="text-center">PRODUCTOS</h2>
      <p class="text-center">Este es nuestro catalogo de productos</p>
      <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
        <div class="contenedor-carousel">
           <div class="carousel">
            <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal1.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div> 
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal2.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal3.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal4.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal5.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal6.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal7.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal8.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Estos códigos me ayudan a desplazar el carousel a la izquierda y derecha, lo que necesito es que cuando al dar click para que siga avanzando a la derecha se detecte que el scroll esta al final del carousel y se regrese al inicio, y cuando el scroll este en el inicio y se de click para que avance a la izquierda se regrese al final.

También tengo otro problema cuando muevo el scroll no hace el desplazamiento correctamente ya que al inicio del primer elemento y al final del ultimo elemento les deja un pequeño espacio, ojala que también pudieran ayudarme a corregir ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres simular desplazamiento circular? o que simplemente ¿salte al extremo del otro lado? para detectar agrega las clases first y last a los elementos extremos cuando cambie la visibilidad de las imágenes verificas si la imagen que se hace visible tiene una de esas dos clases

Answer (score 0):

Basicamende se debe detectar cuando el scroll alcanza el final del espacio disponible (scrollWidth) o el inicio del scroll (scrollLeft==0)

```
$(flechaDerecha).on("click", function(){    
     var scrollDer = fila.scrollLeft() + fila.width();
     if(fila.scrollLeft()+fila.width()/2>=fila[0].scrollWidth){
        scrollDer = fila[0].scrollWidth-fila.width();        
     }
     if(fila.scrollLeft()+fila.width()>=fila[0].scrollWidth){
        scrollDer = 0;        
     }
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollDer);
     
});

$(flechaIzquierda).on("click", function(){     
     var scrollIzq = fila.scrollLeft() - fila.width(); 
     if(fila.scrollLeft()<=fila.width()){
        scrollIzq=0;
     }
     if(fila.scrollLeft()<=0){
        scrollIzq=fila[0].scrollWidth-fila.width();
     }
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollIzq);
});
```

En el ejemplo, al detectar el final derecho, establece el scroll en 0. Y al detectar el inicio, establece el scroll al final (scrollWidth menos el ancho del item).

Las flechas no estan visibles

```js
var fila = $('.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel');
var flechaIzquierda = $('#flecha-izquierda');
var flechaDerecha = $('#flecha-derecha');

$(flechaDerecha).on("click", function(){    
     var scrollDer = fila.scrollLeft() + fila.width();
     if(fila.scrollLeft()+fila.width()/2>=fila[0].scrollWidth){
        scrollDer = fila[0].scrollWidth-fila.width();        
     }
     if(fila.scrollLeft()+fila.width()>=fila[0].scrollWidth){
        scrollDer = 0;        
     }
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollDer);
     
});

$(flechaIzquierda).on("click", function(){     
     var scrollIzq = fila.scrollLeft() - fila.width(); 
     if(fila.scrollLeft()<=fila.width()){
        scrollIzq=0;
     }
     if(fila.scrollLeft()<=0){
        scrollIzq=fila[0].scrollWidth-fila.width();
     }
     fila.scrollLeft(scrollIzq);
});
```

```css
/* Carousel Productos y Categorias */
    
    .panel{
        width: 280px;
        height: 331px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .a-carrito{
        color: #FF0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 230px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .producto .panel-body{
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
    
    .panel img{
        display: block;
        width: 140px;
        height: 210px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .panel .p-precio{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #3FDE20;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    
    .panel .p-producto{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha{
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: #000;
        font-size: 40px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 40%;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 500;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .2s ease all;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda{
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha{
        right: 0;
    }
    
    /* ---- ----- ----- Carousel ----- ----- ----- */
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 33px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto{
        min-width: 280px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        transition: .3s ease all;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto.hover{
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transform-origin: center;
    }



.flecha-izquierda, .flecha-derecha{
  opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productos-recomendados">
      <h2 class="text-center">PRODUCTOS</h2>
      <p class="text-center">Este es nuestro catalogo de productos</p>
      <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
        <div class="contenedor-carousel">
           <div class="carousel">
            <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal1.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal1</p>
              </div>
             </div> 
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal2.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal2</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal3.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal3</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal4.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal4</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal5.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal5</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal6.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal6</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal7.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal7</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default producto">
              <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
              <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="img/sal8.jpg">
               <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
               <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal8</p>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ha funcionado satisfactoriamente, pero tengo una pregunta cuando el scroll llega al final del carousel corta el ultimo elemento cuando que debería mostrarlo completo, de igual forma sucede cuando regresa al inicio corta el primer elemento, como podría solucionarlo??

Comment: En el ejemplo se muestra completamente el primero y el ultimo en cada caso, pero pueden haber diferencias de estilo. Puedes compartir en tu pregunta una captura de como se ve al llegar al inicio o al final?

Comment: Listo, he añadido capturas de como se ve

Comment: Pareciera que el contenedor de scroll tuviera algun tipo de margen horizontal negativo, de otro modo no podria salirse del borde. Puedes inspeccionar el contenedor que hace scroll para ver si el primer elemento `panel` es superpuesto por algo mas de algun contenedor externo

Comment: En mis casos que presento lo que sucede es que debido a las sumas y restas que se hacen durante cada desplazamiento, en ocasiones el scroll no llega al inicio o al final del contenedor

Comment: Agregue una condicion adicional para los casos cuando no alcanza el borde pueda ajustarse a este, antes de hacer el ciclo al otro extremo del contenedor

Comment: Sigue sin alcanzar los bordes para los dos casos